# Sprites failing to update properly

Tags: c#, performance, xna

I have a simple 2D top down survival game where the player simply has to 'run away'/ not collide with the enemies on screen for 30 seconds each round.

After every increment in level the number of each enemy increases.

**The Problem**

One of my enemy types is in a searching/sleeping state until the player comes a certain distance towards it, then it is in a chasing state, and stays that way until the round ends.

On the earlier rounds where there's only around 30 enemies on screen at once all behaviours work fine. However when i start getting to around a 60+ enemy count this certain enemy seems to chase the player for a little while then seems to go back into the sleeping state - which seems odd considering the following;

```
public override void Update(SpriteManager inManager)
{
    this.spriteRectangle.X = (int)position.X;
    this.spriteRectangle.Y = (int)position.Y;

        if (this.collisionRectangle.Intersects(inManager.player.spriteRectangle))
            this.spriteState = SpriteState.Chasing;

        if (this.spriteState == SpriteState.Chasing)
        {
            CheckForPlayer(inManager);
            if (this.spriteRectangle.Intersects(inManager.player.spriteRectangle))
            {
                inManager.player.spriteState = SpriteState.Dead;   
            }
        }


    base.Update(inManager);
}
private void CheckForPlayer(SpriteManager inManager)
{
    if (this.position.X > inManager.player.position.X)
       this.position.X -= X_SPEED;
    else
        this.position.X += X_SPEED;

    if (this.position.Y > inManager.player.position.Y)
        this.position.Y -= Y_SPEED;
    else
        this.position.Y += Y_SPEED;
}
```

Can anyone shed any light onto why they think this problem is occurring, my only thoughts are that with a high sprite (maximum is 108) maybe they're all not having time to check for the player, although when I think about that more to me it makes no sense.

Cheers

Comment: Can you debug it a little further? Check if when it stops moving, if the state is `Chasing` or if It really did switch states. Maybe this could be a problem of more lag with more enemies?

Comment: Was a problem with the players state - so thanks for making me check that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without full code it is hard to tell, but I take it it is a little mistake somewhere. You should try debugging it and checking if the state is `Chasing` or if it really did change states. I've also ran into problems with lag with certain amounts of objects (Probably not the problem) so that could also be a possibility.